# Validate custom form using sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, formfield

I'm creating a form using sharepoint designer 2010, by inserting New Items forms, and editing as necessary the design.

Previously I was using asp:TextBox and validating through

> asp:RegularExpressionValidator

, but for some reason when user selects submit the postback is not working. Then found out SharePoint:FormField postback is working.

I need a way to validate the

> SharePoint:FormField

. I would like to validate using regular expressions. Or fix my postback problem using asp:TextBox, any solution where I can validate and postback would work.

Small side note, I cannot use InfoPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out why the postback wasn't working, when using the asp:TextBox and validating through asp:RegularExpressionValidator. Its because I replaced the "SharePoint:SaveButton" with an input button.

So for postback to work Keep "SharePoint:SaveButton".